How to activate specific chrome profiles with autohotkey, not run
I have 20 google chrome profiles, and I need to select a specific profile from the 20 profiles already running, namely select, and not restart-open a new tab. I implemented this through the MouseClick transition, but it's too long, and I can't get the right ProcessID for a certain profile, help
Profile := "Default"    ;set the specific profile
    for process in ComObjGet("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'chrome.exe'") {
        Commandline := process.Commandline
        str := process.ProcessId              
        StringReplace Parameters, Commandline, % Process.ExecutablePath
        StringReplace Parameters, Parameters, ""
        IfInString, Parameters, Profile
        {
           WinActivate ahk_pid %str%        
           Break
        }
    }
    return
}

